# How does R Markdown automatically format print effects into dataframes? Or how can I access special print methods?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working with the WRS2 package and there are cases where it'll output its analysis (`bwtrim`) into a list with a special class of the analysis type `class = "bwtrim"`. I can't `as.data.frame()` it, but I found that there is a custom print method called `print.bwtrim` associated with it.

As an example let's say this is the output: `bwtrim.out <- bwtrim(...)`. When I run the analysis output in an Rmarkdown chunk, it seems to "steal" part of the text output and make it into a dataframe.

So here's my question, how can I either access `print.bwtrim` or how does R markdown automatically format certain outputs into dataframes? Because I'd like to take this outputted dataframe and use it for other purposes.

---

Update: Here is a minimally working example -- put the following in a chunk in Rmd file."

````
```{r}
library(WRS2)


df <-
  data.frame(
    subject = rep(c(1:100), each = 2),
    group = rep(c("treatment", "control"), each = 2),
    timepoint = rep(c("pre", "post"), times = 2),
    dv = rnorm(200, mean = 2)
  )

analysis <- WRS2::bwtrim(dv ~ group * timepoint,
                         id = subject,
                         data = df,
                         tr = .2)

analysis
```
````

With this, a `data.frame` automatically shows up in the chunk afterwards and it shows all the values very nicely. My main question is how can I get this data.frame for my own uses. Because if you do `str(analysis)`, you see that it's a list. If you do `class(analysis)` you get `"bwtrim"`. if you do `methods(class = "bwtrim")`, you get the print method. And `methods(print)` will have a line that says `print.bwtrim*`. But I can't seem to figure out how to call `print.bwtrim` myself.

---

Regarding what Rmarkdown is doing, compare the following

If you run this in a chunk, it actually steals the data.frame part and puts it into a separate figure.

````
```{r}
capture.output(analysis)
```
````

However, if you run the same line in the console, the entire output comes out properly. What's also interesting is that if you try to assign it to another object, the output will be stolen before it can be assigned.

Compare `x` when you run the following in either a chunk or the console.

````
```{r}
x<-capture.output(analysis)
```
````

This is what I get from the chunk approach when I call x

```
[1] "Call:"                                                        
[2] "WRS2::bwtrim(formula = dv ~ group * timepoint, id = subject, "
[3] "    data = df, tr = 0.2)"                                     
[4] ""                                                             
[5] ""
```

This is what I get when I do it all in the console

```
[1] "Call:"                                                        
[2] "WRS2::bwtrim(formula = dv ~ group * timepoint, id = subject, "
[3] "    data = df, tr = 0.2)"                                     
[4] ""                                                             
[5] "                 value df1     df2 p.value"                   
[6] "group           1.0397   1 56.2774  0.3123"                   
[7] "timepoint       0.0001   1 57.8269  0.9904"                   
[8] "group:timepoint 0.5316   1 57.8269  0.4689"                   
[9] ""
```

---

My question is what can I call whatever Rstudio/Rmarkdown is doing to make `data.frames`, so that I can have an easy data.frame myself?

---

Update 2: This is probably not a bug, as discussed here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1150.

---

Update 3: You can access the method by using `WRS2:::bwtrim(analysis)`, though I'm still interested in what Rmarkdown is doing.

---

Update 4: It might not be the case that Rmarkdown is stealing the output and automatically making dataframes from it, as you can see when you call x after you've already captured the output. Looking at `WRS2:::print.bwtrim`, it prints a dataframe that it creates, which I'm guessing Rmarkdown recognizes then formats it out.

See below for the `print.bwtrim`.

```r
function (x, ...) 
{
    cat("Call:\n")
    print(x$call)
    cat("\n")
    dfx <- data.frame(value = c(x$Qa, x$Qb, x$Qab), df1 = c(x$A.df[1], 
        x$B.df[1], x$AB.df[1]), df2 = c(x$A.df[2], x$B.df[2], 
        x$AB.df[2]), p.value = c(x$A.p.value, x$B.p.value, x$AB.p.value))
    rownames(dfx) <- c(x$varnames[2], x$varnames[3], paste0(x$varnames[2], 
        ":", x$varnames[3]))
    dfx <- round(dfx, 4)
    print(dfx)
    cat("\n")
}
<bytecode: 0x000001f587dc6078>
<environment: namespace:WRS2>
```

Comment: Are you using WRS2 or WRSS? There doesn't seem to be a package called WRS on CRAN

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: @EmilyKothe My bad, it was WRS2.

Comment: @BenBolker I've updated it now

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution or something just for this function in WRS2?

Comment: @EmilyKothe General solution would be best,  but at least specific enough that it covers this particular function. *I've just found the solution for this specific function, but I'm still interested in what Rmarkdown/Knitr is doing to be able to print things into data.frames so easily

Comment: I think the answer to this is: Rmarkdown uses `sink` to retain the output from all code evaluated within the document and present its outputs separately. So when `print.bwtrim` gets called, RMarkdown captures the output and formats its for use in the document.

Answer (score 0):

In R Markdown documents, automatic printing is done by `knitr::knit_print` rather than `print`.  I don't think there's a `knit_print.bwtrim` method defined, so it will use the default method, which is defined as

```
function (x, ..., inline = FALSE) 
{
    if (inline) 
        x
    else normal_print(x)
}
```

and `normal_print` will call `print()`.

You are asking why the output is different.  I don't see that when I knit the document to `html_document`, but I do see it with `html_notebook`.  I don't know the details of what is being done, but if you look at https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebook_format.html you can see a discussion of "output source functions", which manipulate chunks to produce different output.

The fancy output you're seeing looks a lot like what `knitr::knit_print` does for a dataframe, so maybe `html_notebook` is substituting that in place of `print`.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I was looking for... So yes, it's for chunk output within the notebook. I'll look more into the `knitr::knit_print` though, as it seems to be related to [paged.printing](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-stop-paged-printing-of-data-frames-within-function/14682).

Comment: I guess a better form of my question would be, "How does Rmarkdown automatically scan `print` output and make data.frames out of it? And can you use its method for extracting dataframes yourself?"

Comment: I am not familiar with `html_notebook` internals, but I would guess it doesn't scan `print` output, instead it installs its own `print` function, or maybe just a `print.data.frame` method, hiding the standard one.